# Firebase notifcations works on android, not ios (ionic 3)

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-notifications

Got an iPhone and an Android app with notifications using the firebase plugin. It all works fine on android but I don’t get any notifications on ios. I’ve made sure to tick “Push Notifications” on xcode, but that doesn’t do the trick. What could this be due to? In my ionic root folder I have the GoogleService-Info.plist but it doesn’t automatically copy to the ios folder. Instead I do that manually. I don’t know if this could be the cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I found the solution. For iOs you need to manually ask for permission. I thought this was the default behaviour. Thanks for the help!

```
if(platform.is('ios')) {
    window['FirebasePlugin'].grantPermission();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to send notification from Firebase console or somewhere else?

Comment: No I'm posting to firebase via a server. It's unfortunately already in production.. I only have an android phone so I didn't know.

Comment: then how will you check it? did you add pushnotification to certificates when you download it from your account.?

Comment: did you add APNs Authentication Key in firebase's ios app?

Answer (score 0):

Check for message payload :

```
let params: NSMutableDictionary? = ["registration_ids":"ReceiverFcmToken",
                                            "notification" :[
                                                "title": "",
                                                "body": ""] ,
                                            "priority": "high",
                                            "data" :[ "message":[
                                                "KEY":"",
                                                "NOTIType":"","NOTYMessg":"",
                                                "SRCName":accName,
                                                "SRCPhNum":accPhone]],
                                            "content-available" : "1",
                                            "sound": "default"]
```

If you are using any API to send to server, you must need server side code separatly for ios and Android like below:

```
if (Android)
               {
                   string tickerText = "Order Message From Kirana Kart";
                   string contentTitle = "Order Details";                       
                   postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceID + "\" ], " +
                                 "\"data\": {\"message\":" + json + "}}";
               }
               else if (IOS)
               {
                   postData =
                   "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceID + "\" ], " +
                      "\"priority\": \"high\"," +
                      "\"notification\":{ \"title\" : \"AppName\",\"body\" : \"You have received new order\",\"noteID\":\"10\",\"content-available\":\"1\"}," +
                    "\"data\":{\"message\":" + json + "}}";
               }
```